# How do I use a string method inside a string prototype extension method

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I have the following javascript method:

```
String.prototype.includesAny = function(search) {
  var found = false;
  search.forEach(function(str) {
    if(this.toLowerCase().includes(str.toLowerCase())) {
      found = true;
    }
  });
  return found;
};
```

But it throws the error:

> `this.toLowerCase` is not a function

I am thinking this is because `this` is not actually an instance of `String` at this point?  Anybody knows the right way to do what I'm doing (and still use the prototype paradigm)?

Comment: You have not bound the callback function to `this`. use the [`thisArg` argument of `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Comment: Just a side note: this is not the very effective implementation. You will keep scanning an array after you have found first matching string, which is meaningless. You can just return `true` whenever you have found the first match.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript `this` is function scoped, so creating a new function creates a new `this`.

Your `forEach` call has a callback, which is a function, and within that function `this` is no longer the string, but most likely the window

The solution is to simply store a reference to whatever `this` is in the outer function

```
String.prototype.includesAny = function(search) {
    var found = false,
        input = this;
    search.forEach(function(str) {
        if (input.toLowerCase().includes(str.toLowerCase())) {
            found = true;
        }
    });
    return found;
};
```

`Array.forEach` also has an optional `thisArg` that can be used

```
String.prototype.includesAny = function(search) {
    var found = false;

    search.forEach(function(str) {
        if (this.toLowerCase().includes(str.toLowerCase())) {
            found = true;
        }
    }, this);
    return found;
};
```

Or even better, use `Array.some`

```
String.prototype.includesAny = function(search) {
    return search.some(function(str) {
        return this.toLowerCase().includes(str.toLowerCase());
    }, this);
};
```

As a sidenote, extending native prototypes is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably correct about `this` not being a string because you are in the `foreach`.  So store an instance of `this` in a variable before entering the `foreach` and use that instead.

```
var stringToCheck = this;
search.forEach(function...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your `this` in other variable to use it in other functions scope.